# Conversion of ASCII (I think) using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

Hope you can help me, I am a bit of a newbie and have progressed without needing help but now I am stuck.

Firstly could somebody please tell me what this is below, I think it is ASCII but maybe wrong???

```
"\0\u{01}\0\0\0\u{1E}\0\0\u{02}\u{06}\0ÿ\0\0\0\0\0\u{02}.\u{01}(\0\t\0ü\0\u{07}\0\u{04}"
```

Secondly how would I convert this to an NSArray so I could get iterate through it and get a value at a given location in the array?

I am using Swift

Many thanks in advance
Charles

Comment: It would help if you could explain the context of where you got that string and how. Show the code that printed or logged it, as well. It's not ASCII. It looks like binary data that's been encoded using backslash escaping.

Comment: \u{...} represents a unicode char.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, your string looks quite weird, and the \u{xx} values tell Swift to replace that part with the unicode character corresponding to hexadecimal value xx (see [unicode-table](http://unicode-table.com/en/)).

I do not know why you would want to convert it to the Objective-C type `NSArray` while you could just use the Swift type `Array`. By that, I mean you can generate an array of the string by using `var strArray = Array(str)`, where your string is stored in `str`. From that point on, you can use the following code to iterate over the contents of the string:

```
for var char in strArray {
  //do something with char
}
```

`char` then loops through all indices of the strArray, holding the value at the current index.

Comment: Thanks for he responses, this is the ascii string encoding from the raw data supplied from the server.  Think that I maybe should not encode it, but having trouble working with the data.